# .NET MAUI Pass Value from TabBar/ShellContent to Target Page

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a very simple TabBar with a few ShellContent elements such as this:

```
 <ShellContent
    Title="Staying at Home"
    Icon="house_user_solid.png"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PatientEdSelectionPage}">

    <views:PatientEdSelectionPage />
</ShellContent>
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace Lati2d.ViewMode  
{
  public partial class PatientEdViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
      public ObservableCollection<PatientEd> PatientEds { get; } = new();
      public ObservableCollection<Lati2d.Model.Condition> Conditions { get; } = new();
      public string PatientEd { get; set; }
      public string PatientEdTypeId { get; set; }
      public Guid ConditionId { get; set; }
      public string ConditionName { get; set; }
      public Lati2d.Model.Condition SelectedCondition { get; set; }

      PatientEdService _patientEdService;
      ConditionService _conditionService;
      public PatientEdViewModel(
          PatientEdService patientEdService,
          ConditionService conditionService)
      {
          _patientEdService = patientEdService;
          _conditionService = conditionService;

          Title = "Patient Education Titles";
      }
   }
}
```

This all works great.  I'm now trying to get a value from the ShellContent to the page.  I'm happy to pass some sort of parameter or use some sort of reference from the Page, back to the 'referrer'.

I've tried the QueryParameter attribute and a few other methods I've seen, most seem to use direct navigation, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Post the code you tried, so people can suggest ways to fix it. It may be a case for setting the name of the parameter right. Passing parameter is so common, that the first person that sees it will answer.

Comment: With respect, the code is posted. I don't want to try an make my failed attempts work, I'm asking how to properly do it based on the code posted.  If this is as common as you say (and IMO, it certainly should be) it should take nothing for someone with more experience than me to post the method.

Comment: (1) Create a GlobalViewModel singleton, (2) optional set the App BindingContext to the GlobalViewModel or make the GlobalViewModel available everywhere (e.g. dependency injection).

Comment: @StevenFrank the method is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Comment: Thanks @H.A.H. That looks pretty good.  I think the piece I've been missing is the event handler (which without parameters is unnecessary).  I presume navigating from the click/tap handler will preempt the normal navigation of the click or do I have to explicitly cancel it?

Comment: @StevenFrank No no no. Stephen Quan's GlobalViewModel suggestion will be better compared to this. Much better actually.

Comment: @Stephen Quan 1) I'm not sure what you mean by GlobalViewModel 2) I presume this replaces my assignment of the page-specific ViewModel to the BindingContext?  3) As you can see, I'm already using DI for everything so I think this is how I would want to do it (but I still have no idea how)

Comment: I fear my initial intent is being lost in this thread.  Put simply, I need to either 1) pass a simple value from a ShellContent in a TabBar to the Page is calls OR 2) get a handle on the 'clicked' tab from the page.  I just want to know which tab was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rewrote answer]

Instead of inlining `PatientEdSelectionPage`:

```xml
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PatientEdSelectionPage}"/>
```

Consider expanding it then, you can easily add properties:

```xml
<ShellContent>
    <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:PatientEdSelectionPage SomeProperty="SomeValue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
</ShellContent>
```

Also, you may also like to use `StaticResource`

```xml
    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="patientEdSelectionTemplate">
                <local:PatientEdSelectionPage SomeProperty="SomeValue"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Tab Title="PatientEdSelection">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{StaticResource patientEdSelectionTemplate}"/>
    </Tab>
```

[Old Answer]

This answer involves passing properties throughout your entire application via a `GlobalViewModel` singleton.

```cs
public partial class GlobalViewModel : BaseViewModel
```

As you're using Dependency Injection, set it up like this:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<PatientEdViewModel>();
```

In your `AppShell.xaml.cs`, you can gain access to the `GlobalViewModel` singleton. That way, the Shell can provide values via the `GlobalViewModel` singleton.

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public GlobalViewModel Global { get; }

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Global = IPlatformApplication.Current.Services.GetService<GlobalViewModel>();
        BindingContext = Global;
        // set BindingContext to either this or Global.
        // Does not matter.
        // Either way, we enable `GlobalViewModel` in the Shell XAML
    }
}
```

Because `GlobalViewModel` is a singleton, you can set properties from `Shell` and you can consume those same properties in `PatentEdViewModel`. For the latter, you can configure `PatentEdViewModel` via dependency injection:

```cs
public PatientEdViewModel(
          PatientEdService patientEdService,
          ConditionService conditionService,
          GlobalViewModel globalViewModel)
      {
          _patientEdService = patientEdService;
          _conditionService = conditionService;
          _globalViewModel = globalViewModel;
```

The comment about declaring `GlobalViewModel` in the `App` `BindingContext` should allow access to the `GlobalViewModel` in your bindings, by setting `Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:GlobalViewModel}}`, but, setting it as a dependency to your individual view models works too.

Comment: I apologize in advance for being an idiot, but I still have no idea what that has to do with my TabBar.

Comment: Ok, @StevenFrank, I've added snippets of `AppShell.xaml.cs` relating to how to gain access to the `GlobalViewModel` singleton.

Comment: Thank you, I can understand that.  I really appreciate your time.